# Удаление записей из xml-файла с использованием ClientDataSet

Tags: delphi

Доброго времени суток всем. Говорят, что жизнь без проблем скучна, но я бы хотел пожить без проблем хотя бы годик. Я работаю с xml файлом, и мне нужно удалить все записи.
Мой код:

```
if dm.ClientDataSet2.Active=false then dm.ClientDataSet2.Open;
dm.ClientDataSet2.Edit;
dm.ClientDataSet2.First;
while not(dm.ClientDataSet2.RecordCount=0) do dm.ClientDataSet2.delete;
dm.ClientDataSet2.SaveToFile();
dm.ClientDataSet2.MergeChangeLog;
```

При первом нажатии кнопки ничего не происходит, при втором нажатии в файле остается часть записей, только с третьего раза файл полностью очищается. Подскажите, что тут не так? В коде, вроде, все нормально.

Comment: Отформатируйте код используя кнопку **101010**,а то читать не возможно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если попробовать

```
while not dm.ClientDataSet2.IsEmpty do dm.ClientDataSet2.delete;
```

И Next в цикле не нужно ставить, т.к. после удаления записи курсор переходит на следующую запись и если воткнуть еще и Next после удаления, то получится что удаляться будет каждая вторая запись
Еще попробуйте удалить вот эту строку

```
dm.ClientDataSet2.Edit;
```

При удалении не нужно вставать в режим редактирования, достаточно открыть датасет.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот

```
  dm.ClientDataSet2.First;
```

Я вижу а где у Вас

```
dm.ClientDataSet2.Next;
```

Да и вместо

```
while not(dm.ClientDataSet2.RecordCount=0) do
```

Наверное лучше использовать

```
while not(dm.ClientDataSet2.EOF) do
```

Comment: Последовал вашему совету, результат такой же. В файле у меня всего 270 записей и 6-ть колонок.

Comment: По Вашему кусочку кода , ничего толком не понятно.
То что Я посоветовал, это то что сразу бросилось в глаза, да и сама постановка задачи весьма размытая.
Сформулируйте все нормальным можно нудным разжованным языком.

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался